# Where or how do I get replacement stickers for my LEGO set?

Tags: shopping, stickers

I have a BMW Williams F1 LEGO set 8461 that I built when I got it several years ago.  I unfortunately let it sit out on my shelf for a long time.  The stickers have peeled and cracked and some have nearly disintegrated.

How or where do I get a new sheet of stickers so I can rebuild the model properly and then have it put in a case so I can help keep this from happening again?

---

UPDATE (put this here as it would not fit in the comments).

I got my response back from LEGO.  The set is too old and they do not carry that set of stickers any more.

> Dear Scott,
>
> Thanks for getting in touch with us.
>
> We're sorry we no longer have the stickers you need. We try really hard to keep as many replacement LEGO® parts as we can, but sometimes we run out of pieces from old sets. A second hand toy expert or collector might be able to help, or you could even try searching at flea markets or second hand shops.
>
> Thank you again for contacting us. If you have any further questions, please feel free to reply to this email or call one of our friendly Customer Care Advisors at 1-800-835-4386 (from within the US or Canada) or 1-860-749-0706 (from outside the US or Canada). We are available Monday through Friday from 8AM - 10PM EST and Saturday through Sunday from 10AM to 6PM EST.
>
> Daniel
>   LEGO Direct Consumer Services

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can either buy them on [BrickLink](http://bricklink.com), or contact [LEGO Customer Service](http://service.lego.com) directly. BrickLink might be the cheaper of the two options, but if LEGO has them in stock, they are guaranteed to be factory-new.

Comment: I just checked BrickLink and there don't seem to be complete sticker sheet available.  All of the sets they have for sale all seem to have the stickers that are poor similar shape as too mine.  I will give Lego a try and cross my fingers.

Answer (score 17):

For older sets, you can buy replicas made by [some Dutch fans](http://www.ministickers.nl/shop/). I've met them on a few occasions and have seen the stickers they make and quite frankly, the quality is excellent. As far as I can see they don't do Technic sets yet, but it can't hurt to ask.

Granted, they are not genuine, but for genuine LEGO sticker sheets you'll usually end up paying a fortune, and then they'll peel off anyway.

For genuine stickers, don't forget eBay or even [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=8461+replacement+sticker+sheet).

Comment: we occasionally also do technic stickers indeed, currently I'm trying to reproduce the Ferrari set.

Comment: oh! it would be my very happy day if you could make replacement stickers for set 6450!
http://bricks.argz.com/part/6450stk01 for reference. I certainly would buy these.

Answer (score 6):

For long-retired products, it may be possible to find scanned images of the stickers online.

Then use a high quality color printer to print new decals which you glue to the bricks.

The result is not perfect, but often good enough to fool an untrained eye.